# Should combining memory fence for mutex acquire-exchange loop (or queue acquire-load loop) be done or should it be avoided?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, memory-barriers

Assume a repeated acquire operation, that tries to load or exchange a value until the observed value is the desired value.

Let's take [cppreference atomic flag example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) as a starting point:

```
void f(int n)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 100; ++cnt) {
        while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))  // acquire lock
             ; // spin
        std::cout << "Output from thread " << n << '\n';
        lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);               // release lock
    }
}
```

Now let's consider enhancements to this spinning. Two well-known are:

- Don't spin forever, instead go to OS wait at some point;
- Use an instruction, such as `pause` or `yield` instead of no-operation spinning.

I can think of a third, and I'm wondering if it ever makes sense.
We can use `std::atomic_thread_fence` for acquire semantic:

```
void f(int n)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 100; ++cnt) {
        while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed))  // acquire lock
             ; // spin
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);  // acquire fence
        std::cout << "Output from thread " << n << '\n';
        lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);               // release lock
    }
}
```

I expect that to be no change for x86.

I'm wondering:

- Is there benefits or drawbacks from this change on platforms where there is a difference (ARM)?
- Is there any interference with the decision to use or not to use `yield` instruction?

---

I'm not only interested in `atomic_flag::clear` / `atomic_flag::test_and_set` pair, I'm also interested in `atomic<uint32_t>::store` /  `atomic<uint32_t>::load` pair.

---

Possibly changing to relaxed load could make sense:

```
void f(int n)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 100; ++cnt) {
        while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))  // acquire lock
             while (lock.test(std::memory_order_relaxed))
                 YieldProcessor(); // spin
        std::cout << "Output from thread " << n << '\n';
        lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);               // release lock
    }
}
```

Comment: `instruction, such as pause or yield` While I see [pause instruction in x86](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_232.html) it is just a hint to cpu, and there is no `yield` instruction. If you meant [pause(2)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pause.html) then it waits for an interrupt, and if you meant [shed_yield](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) then you shouldn't use it - `sched_yield` is meant for realtime processes and your code will then just use 100% cpu with the scheduler blocking other processes.

Comment: `yield` is ARM instruction. I meant that. On x86 this is a question about nothing anyway, so I mentioned ARM instruction. I mean here CPU instructions, no operating system or runtime library functions.

Comment: And yes, this a question about making optimization hints, so `pause` / `yield` are indeed 'hint' instructions.

Comment: Yes, the general idea of avoiding an acquire barrier inside the failure retry path is possibly useful, although performance in the failure case is barely relevant if you're just spinning.  But that's why CAS has separate `memory_order` parameters for success and failure.  Relaxed failure could let the compiler only barrier on the leave-the-loop path.  `atomic_flag` `test_and_set` doesn't have that option, though.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about "the performance of just spinning". I suspect there is some sense behind it, otherwise there weren't a `pause` / `yield` instruction. Thanks for mentioning CAS with separate ordering parameters -- I now see why these separate parameters are useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the general idea of avoiding an acquire barrier inside the failure retry path is possibly useful, although performance in the failure case is barely relevant if you're just spinning.  `pause` or `yield` save power.  On x86, `pause` also improves SMT friendlyness, and avoids memory-order mis-speculation when leaving the loop after another core modified the memory location you're spinning on.

But that's why CAS has separate `memory_order` parameters for success and failure.  Relaxed failure could let the compiler only barrier on the leave-the-loop path.

`atomic_flag` `test_and_set` doesn't have that option, though.  **Doing it manually potentially hurts ISAs like AArch64 that could have done an acquire RMW and avoided an explicit fence instruction.  (e.g. with `ldarb`)**

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:7,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:7,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:7,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:7,startLineNumber:18),source:'%23include+%3Cthread%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A+%0Astd::atomic_flag+lock+%3D+ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT%3B%0A+%0Avoid+f(int+n)%0A%7B%0A++++for+(int+cnt+%3D+0%3B+cnt+%3C+100%3B+%2B%2Bcnt)+%7B%0A++++++++while+(lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))++//+acquire+lock%0A+++++++++++++%3B+//+spin%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Output+from+thread+%22+%3C%3C+n+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B%0A++++++++lock.clear(std::memory_order_release)%3B+++++++++++++++//+release+lock%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+g(int+n)%0A%7B%0A++++for+(int+cnt+%3D+0%3B+cnt+%3C+100%3B+%2B%2Bcnt)+%7B%0A++++++++while+(lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed))++//+acquire+lock%0A+++++++++++++%3B+//+spin%0A++++++++std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)%3B++//+acquire+fence%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Output+from+thread+%22+%3C%3C+n+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B%0A++++++++lock.clear(std::memory_order_release)%3B+++++++++++++++//+release+lock%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.11175467898498,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g820,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:11,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:48.888245321015035,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4): Original loop with `lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)`:

```
# AArch64 gcc8.2 -O3
.L6:                            # do{
    ldaxrb  w0, [x19]           # acquire load-exclusive
    stxrb   w1, w20, [x19]      # relaxed store-exclusive
    cbnz    w1, .L6            # LL/SC failure retry
    tst     w0, 255
    bne     .L6             # }while(old value was != 0)
  ... no barrier after this
```

(And yes, it looks like a missed optimization that it's only testing the low 8 bits with `tst` instead of just `cbnz w1, .L6`)

while(relaxed RMW) + `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);`

```
.L14:                          # do {
    ldxrb   w0, [x19]             # relaxed load-exclusive
    stxrb   w1, w20, [x19]        # relaxed store-exclusive
    cbnz    w1, .L14             # LL/SC retry
    tst     w0, 255
    bne     .L14               # }while(old value was != 0)
    dmb     ishld         #### Acquire fence
   ...
```

**It's even worse for 32-bit ARMv8** where `dmb ishld` isn't available, or compilers don't use it.  **You'll get a `dmb ish` full barrier.**

---

#### Or with `-march=armv8.1-a`

```
.L2:
    swpab   w20, w0, [x19]
    tst     w0, 255
    bne     .L2
    mov     x2, 19
  ...
```

vs.

```
.L9:
    swpb    w20, w0, [x19]
    tst     w0, 255
    bne     .L9
    dmb     ishld                   # acquire barrier (load ordering)
    mov     x2, 19
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I expect it to apply to `store`-release / `load`-acquire loop as well (the same way, but without LL/SC).

Comment: I assume that the existence of this situation when separate `atomic_thread_fence` is worse is strong argument against ever doing it in a generic implementation, as it is pessimization of **fast path** whereas potential optimization is an **optimization of waiting**

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Yes, exactly.  ARMv8 is an interesting case where an acquire *operation* is significantly cheaper than an acquire *fence*.  Many other weakly-ordered ISAs would have an equivalent fence as part of an acquire operation.  But with ARM being a very relevant / important ISA these days, that's good reason to care about its special case.

Comment: Looks like having just one fence, but still use ARM instruction is possible, I've added another code variant

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: Right, spinning read-only until it looks like there's a chance to take the lock is preferable anyway.  I should have mentioned that, but I was thinking that `atomic_flag` is so primitive it was just TAS and clear.  But yes of course there's a test as well.

Comment: It really was. `atomic_flag::test` is C++20 addition.

Comment: Edited https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag to add an example with `atomic_flag::test` to promote this idea

Answer (score 1):

Pause instruction is just a replacement for N number of NOP instructions, where N vary from processor to processor. Additionally it has an effect on re-ordering of instruction in out-of-order execution capable processors. Whether atomic_thread_fence will provide some benefit over 'pause' depends on what is the typical number of cycles spin-wait loop waits. atomic_thread_fence has a higher execution latency than pause instruction. If spin-waiting cycles are large than other mechanism like using MONITOR-MWAIT instruction pair on x86 platform give better performance and are energy efficient as well. Otherwise pause is good enough.