# Strange atomic_flag example for c++20 at cppreference.com

Tags: c++

cppreference.com [std::atomic_flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) listed two examples of spinlock in prior c++20 and c++20. The last modified date is 21 July 2020, at 12:58.

Prior c++20:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
 
std::atomic_flag lock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
 
void f(int n)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 100; ++cnt) {
        while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))  // acquire lock
             ; // spin
        std::cout << "Output from thread " << n << '\n';
        lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);               // release lock
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        v.emplace_back(f, n);
    }
    for (auto& t : v) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

c++ 20:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
 
std::atomic_flag lock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
 
void f(int n)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 100; ++cnt) {
        while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))  // acquire lock
             while (lock.test(std::memory_order_relaxed))     // test lock
                 ; // spin
        std::cout << "Output from thread " << n << '\n';
        lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);                // release lock
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        v.emplace_back(f, n);
    }
    for (auto& t : v) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Two things that bother me in the c++20 example are:

(1) ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT is deprecated in c++20 and the default constructor should store value to false for us.

(2) <del>The "optimization" by introducing `while (lock.test(std::memory_order_relaxed))`  after the flag has been set to true does not make sense to me. Shouldn't `while (lock.test(std::memory_order_relaxed))`  always immediately return in that case? Why is it an optimization to the prior c++20 example then?</del>

Edit:
c++20 has introduced test() for atomic which simply checks if the flag is true by doing an atomic load. It is placed at the inner loop when test_and_set() has failed so that the computer first spins inside the test() while loop before going back to test_and_set() the second time.

Comment: Why do you think (lock.test(std::memory_order_relaxed))  should always immediately return?

Comment: The inner `while` is only reached if the flag wasn't changed. But I don't understand what it means to optimize a spin operation.

Comment: cppreference.com is just a wiki page... anybody can edit it. even you! It's not the golden standard. The person that added the code doesn't even have an account on the page. Maybe its bad code.

Comment: that edit came from https://stackoverflow.com/q/62318642/2945027

Comment: @Slava I was wrong, lock.test(std::memory_order_relaxed) handled the case where the test_and_set failed. I wrongly took it as in the critical section.

Comment: @Cubbi Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0):

See the comment:

> that edit came from stackoverflow.com/q/62318642/2945027 – Cubbi